# In Airflow UI under connections, what does 'encrypted' and 'extra-encrypted' mean?

Tags: airflow

Simple question here. When looking at Airflow's UI, like in the screenshot below:

[image]

What does `Is Encrypted` and `Is Extra Encrypted` stand for? Is there clear documentation on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- 'Is Encrypted' means a password value were set in the connection and it will be encrypted using a fernet key. You can see more details [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html). When an Apache Airflow enviromente are running with no encryption, even the logs prints the passwords connections for instance.
- 'Is Extra Encrypted' means that whatever were set in Extras dictionary and it will be encrypted or not.

In a first moment, you can imagine that 'Is Extra Encrypted' can be an extra security layer. This is not the case.